JNI Crashing when using from other header file
When i try to use the JNI pointer from another file, the main process crashes, not sure how to look up the crash reason neither.
I've a cpp header file to handle java stuff
using jniGetCreatedJavaVMs_t = jint(*)(JavaVM** vmBuf, jsize bufLen, jsize* nVMs);
inline JavaVM* pJVM = NULL;
inline JNIEnv* pJNI = NULL;

namespace Java
{   
    inline bool HookJVM()
    {
        const HMODULE jvmHandle = GetModuleHandleW(L"jvm.dll");
        if (jvmHandle == nullptr) {
            std::cout << dye::red("[-]") << " Failed to get jvm.dll handle\n";
            return false;
        }
        
        const jniGetCreatedJavaVMs_t jniGetCreatedJavaVMs = reinterpret_cast<jniGetCreatedJavaVMs_t>(GetProcAddress(jvmHandle, "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs"));
        if (jniGetCreatedJavaVMs == nullptr) {
            std::cout << dye::red("[-]") << " Failed to get created JVMs\n";
            return false;
        }
        
        jniGetCreatedJavaVMs(&pJVM, 1, nullptr);
        return true;
    }

if i try to use pJNI inside this file it works, but in the other file the process explodes.
not even sure if its a jni problem 

What "other file" are you talking about? Where do you use/initialize pJNI? Did you take the same-thread restriction re JNIEnv into account? Are you doing any of this inside the DllAttach function? We need more information to help you. The inline bit in your pJVM declaration is also worrying. Is this all inside a header file that is included from mulltiple translation units? (.cpp files)

By "other file" i mean another header file, i initialize pJNI using pJVM->AttachCurrentThread
Thanks for you time

A translation unit is a .cpp file and every header it includes. How many cpp files do you have? Why did you define pJVM as inline? Normally you have extern declarations in headers and a single definition in a cpp file...

The thing is that when i try to use FindClass function, the process crashes, but if i "refresh" the pJNI by calling again AttachCurrentThread function in the file that causes the crash, it works, i dont get why i've to attach again to the thread

As a plain simple debugging step, please print the address of pJNI (so &pJNI, not the contents) in both files. If you have a different address they are different variables. Which, again, is due to your use of inline instead of proper variable linkage. Alternatively, you actually have multiple threads and are trying to share a single JNIEnv between them, which is not allowed. C++ doesn't care much about different files otherwise.

My money is on the latter cause and it can be trivially fixed by using local variables for JNIEnv instead and retrieving it at the start of whatever your root function is per thread.

&pJNI is the same, prints 00007FF8D6BF12A0 both times

Then it's the other thing. You can trivially verify that by attaching a debugger and comparing the current thread when you call ->AttachCurrentThread the first time to when you actually use pJNI. Can't say anything more without more information.

inline JNIEnv* pJNI = NULL; has quite a code smell.  You can't cache a JNIEnv value.  Either you attach a thread to the JVM and use the value JNIEnv value you get and then detach the thread when you're done, or you use the JNIEnv value passed from the JVM when it makes a call into native code.  Nothing else is safe, no matter what you read.
